# How do I use the same event for different buttons in FXML

Tags: java, events, javafx, fxml

The event that I'm talking about is simply this: The moment the user moves the cursor to where the button is at, it will change to a different color. Once it exits, it changes back to the original color. I've already implemented this and all I'm asking is how do I program each button to use the same two events? Remember each button will behave differently but this event will be the same for every button.

Here is the relevant code

**My FXML Controller class**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MenulayoutFXMLController implements Initializable
{   
    @FXML private Button playButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
         Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.mp3").toExternalForm());
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(gameIntroTheme);
         mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
         mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
    }     

    @FXML private void changeNewColor(MouseEvent event)
    {
        playButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0f69b4;");
    }

    @FXML private void backToOldColor(MouseEvent event)
    {
        playButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #346699;");
    }
}
```

**My FXML**

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<StackPane fx:id="MainMenu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.MenulayoutFXMLController">
    <stylesheets>
       <URL value="@ButtonLayout.css"/>
   </stylesheets>
     <children>      
         <ImageView>
             <image>
                <Image url="@ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg"/>
            </image>
        </ImageView>
        <VBox fx:id="MainMenuLayout"  spacing="20"  alignment="TOP_CENTER" > 
            <children>
                 <ImageView>
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                 <Button fx:id="playButton" onMouseEntered="#changeNewColor" onMouseExited="#backToOldColor"  prefWidth="200" prefHeight="30" text="Play" styleClass="ButtonLayout">
                     <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle  width="200" height="30" arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>              
                 <Button fx:id="optionButton" prefWidth="200" prefHeight="30" text="Option" styleClass="ButtonLayout">
                     <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle  width="200" height="30" arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
                 <Button fx:id="aboutTheGameButton" prefWidth="200" prefHeight="30" text="How to Play" styleClass="ButtonLayout">
                     <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle  width="200" height="30" arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
                 <Button fx:id="exitButton"  prefWidth="200" prefHeight="30" text="Exit" styleClass="ButtonLayout">
                     <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle  width="200" height="30" arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </VBox>   
    </children> 
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this with CSS. You don't need any event handling at all:

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: #346699;
}
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #0f69b4;
}
```

Comment: It's active when the mouse hovers over the selected node. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#hoverProperty)

Comment: Well I'm getting a javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,10]